# How do I mirror an NSAttributedString with an icon and text in right-to-left mode

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization, nsattributedstring, right-to-left

I have a `UIButton` that holds an `NSAttributedString` that contains an icon (which is an `NSAttributedString` itself) followed by a text.

It looks something like this:

[image: Button appearance in LTR]

I want to make it look like this when the device is configured for an RTL language (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew):

[image: Desired look in RTL mode]

The string is built like this:

```
var iconText = NSAttributedString(fontName: fontName, fontSize: fontPointSize, fontValue: fontValue, color: color ?? iconColor)
let iconTextRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: iconText.count)
let iconAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: icon.font(pointSize: pointSize),
                                                .foregroundColor: iconColor]

if !text.isEmpty {
    iconText = "\(iconText) \(text)"
}

let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: iconText, attributes: textAttrs)
attributeString.addAttributes(iconAttrs, range: iconTextRange)
return attributeString
```

As you can see, first the icon is created using a font, then it's concatenated to the text.

In other parts of the app, I managed to make `NSAttributedString`'s RTL-compliant with this little piece of code:

```
public extension NSAttributedString {
    /// Returns an identical attributed string that'll adjust its direction based on the device's configured language.
    func rightToLeftAdjusted() -> NSAttributedString {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .natural
        
        let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: length)
        
        let copy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        copy.addAttributes(attrs, range: range)
        
        return copy
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, in this specific case, it doesn't seem to work, the star ALWAYS stays to the left of the text.

Are there any other ways of achieving this?

Comment: Instead of using something like `iconText = "\(iconText) \(text)"`, use `String(format:)`, and localizedString, which would hold, depending on the local `"localizedStr" = "%$1@ %2@"` or `"localizedStr" = "%$2@ %1@"`, and to call it `String(format: LocalizedString(localizedStr), iconText, text)`?

Comment: I did this `let x = NSLocalizedString("%@ %@", comment: "test") 
            iconText = String(format: x, iconText, text)`, didn't work (icon is still to the left). Are you referring to some other class I'm not aware of? I couldn't find anything called `LocalizedString` (googled for it as well)

Comment: I meant `NSLocalizedString`, but it mean that you have a `.strings` file. With translations.

Comment: I used `NSLocalizedString`, and I do have a translations file

Comment: Then, you can use my suggestion, where `localizedStr` is the localized key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped on the matter.

The solution I got to was, instead of appending the icon as a font, I converted it to a `UIImage`, then to an `NSTextAttachment`.

That way, the image flipped to the right side of the text when the app is running in RTL mode.

```
func addDecorator(icon: DrawbleIcon, pointSize: CGFloat, to text: String, textAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

        appendIcon(to: attributedString, icon: icon, pointSize: pointSize)
        
        // Append text
        if !text.isEmpty {
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: textAttrs))
        }
        
        // Adjust text to right-to-left devices
        let writingDirection: NSWritingDirection = UIApplication.isRightToLeft ? .rightToLeft : .leftToRight
        let leftToRightAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.writingDirection: [NSNumber(value: writingDirection.rawValue)]]
        attributedString.addAttributes(leftToRightAttrs, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        
        return attributedString
    }
    
    private func appendIcon(to attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString, icon: DrawbleIcon, pointSize: CGFloat) {
        let iconColor = icon.foreColor
        let iconAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: icon.font(pointSize: pointSize),
                                                        .foregroundColor: iconColor]
        
        if let iconText = icon.attributedString(fontPointSize: pointSize, color: nil),
           let font = iconText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)[.font] as? UIFont,
           let iconImage = NSAttributedString(string: iconText.string, attributes: iconAttrs).image() {
            let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: iconImage)
            let imageSize = iconImage.size
            
            // Fix image height - without this, the image is higher than the text.
            textAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: (font.capHeight - imageSize.height) / 2, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment))
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " "))
        }
    }

private extension String {
    /// Generates a `UIImage` instance from this string using a specified
    /// attributes and size.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - attributes: to draw this string with. Default is `nil`.
    ///     - size: of the image to return.
    /// - Returns: a `UIImage` instance from this string using a specified
    /// attributes and size, or `nil` if the operation fails.
    func image(withAttributes attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil, size: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        let size = size ?? (self as NSString).size(withAttributes: attributes)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { _ in
            (self as NSString).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size),
                                    withAttributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}

private extension NSAttributedString {
    func image(size: CGSize? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        string.image(withAttributes: attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil), size: size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
            if preferredLanguage ==  "en" {
                button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            }else if preferredLanguage == "ar" {
                button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            }
    
    
   
    The source code is at the below repository link:

https://github.com/ahmetbostanciklioglu/ButtonAlignmentLeftToRightAndRightToLeft.git
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(

Comment: have you checked below attached GitHub link, it could help you understand the main of the problem, because it works for me in the repo project